# Login form, validating hashed+salt password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt

In my registration.php form I'm hashing passwords with this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/idWaiRm9)

But when I try to validate correct password in login.php form [pastebin2](http://pastebin.com/rsX6x3bQ) it will evaluate the password as incorrect.

Have you got any idea what is wrong in login validating password?

Comment: Is the password column length large enough to store the hash?

Comment: You should check the values stored in your db cause I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Oh Thank you Marek, the length of password column was too short :) I made it longer Varchar and it works ! :) Thank you